# Display query in jsp using html

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

How do I go about displaying the results of a query from MYSQL in a jsp using html tags? My instructor said to do the query in the .jsp file and use html tags to display the results. What is the correct syntax for this. Can I get an example or a link to a page that will show me. I have no problem writing the query, just unsure about the jsp/html display. Thanks

```
<BODY>
<H2>JSP Expressions</H2>
<UL>
  <LI>Current time: <%= new java.util.Date() %>
  <LI>Your hostname: <%= request.getRemoteHost() %>
  <LI>Your session ID: <%= session.getId() %>
  <LI>The <CODE>testParam</CODE> form parameter:
      <%= request.getParameter("testParam") %>
</UL>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

in jsp we have scriptlet tags ( <%   %> ).you can use the `jdbc` statements between these jsp tags, The below sample code shows the display query in jsp using html,

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.io.*"%>

<html>
<head>
<body background="1.jpg">
<title>ehealthcare advisor</title>
</head>
<body><center>
<h1><center>E-HEALTH CARE ADVISOR</center></h1>
<h4><center>get best solutions in minuites...</center></h4>
<table border="0" cellspacing="50" cell padding="10">
<tr>
  <td> <a href="homepage.jsp">HOME</a></td>
  <td> <a href="userlogin.jsp">LOGOUT</a></td>
<td><a href="aboutus.jsp">ABOUT US</a></td>
</table>
</center>
<center>
<h2>PATIENT LIST</h2>

<table border="1" width="40%">
<thead>
<th>UserId</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Occupation</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Weight</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%
  Statement st = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con   =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ehealthcare","root","root");
st = con.createStatement();
String qry ="select * from user"; 
rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
while(rs.next()){ %>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
</tr>
   <%
}
con.close();
st.close();
  }
   catch(Exception ex){
    out.println(ex);
   }
  %>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, @BalaYesu Chilakalapudi - But I'm not interested in creating a table. I just want to see how the code works, so I can play with it...and make it work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I give the link you refer it.

1. [Jsp Sample Database Access, it is like core java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics7.htm)
2. [Jsp using JSTL tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)
3. [Database from Jsp](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/accessingdatabase-fromjsp.shtml)

If you use No. 2 . **Jsp using JSTL tags**, that will be good programming.

JSTL tags are simple to learn.

Comment: I'm looking at example 1 and I really don't see where the html tags come into play.. It looks as if the output is still done through java code wrapped in jsp tags. Is the above code the same thing? I'm going over some slides from class.

Comment: I kind of rather do it the other way. It is a bit more familiar, and I really don't have the time to learn a new approach with it being in the last 2 weeks of the semester. Thanks for the advice, though. I see that the ResultSet seems to play a heavy role in at least executing the SQL query...